Breaking a strong reference cycle with an explicit 'nil' assignment
This question was driving me crazy for a few days now and nobody could yet give me a clear view on what's actually happening. Here is the first snippet of the code
class Animal {
    var name = "Fischer"
    
    var command: () -> Void = { }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function, #line)
    }
}

do {
    var pet: Animal? = Animal()
    pet?.command = { print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }
}

This code causes a memory leak, because

Reference 'pet' is created.
Independent copy of the reference 'pet' is created inside the closure. now there are two references to the same object, which are 'pet' outside the closure and 'pet' inside the closure.
As we exit the 'do' scope, the 'pet' reference is deleted, but ARC does not deallocate the object due to the strong reference 'pet', that is still referencing to the same object.
And all of that causes a memory leak. Now here is the code, that is pretty similar, except for the fact, that we assign a nil to the 'pet' reference

class Animal {
    var name = "Fischer"
    
    var command: () -> Void = { }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function, #line)
    }
}

do {
    var pet: Animal? = Animal()
    pet?.command = { print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }
    pet = nil
}

And boom! deinit is called, meaning that the object was deallocated, but how? Why was the object deallocated? If we are deleting the exact same reference, that was deleted by the end of the 'do' scope in the first snippet? Am I misunderstanding something? I've been struggling to understand this for a lot of time yet I still don't get how it works.

You have nullified pet, that's mean that pet in closure also doesn't point to anything.

But why? Aren't those the different references? As far as I know, nullifying the reference has nothing to do with an object, since we are deleting the reference to an object, not an object itself. If you are really sure about your answer, then I ask you very much to be patient with me.
Once again, here how it looks from my perspective :
You are saying I nullified the 'pet', but nullifying the pet only deletes one strong reference. And we still have a strong reference, 'pet' that is pointing to the same object from inside the closure. But for some reason the object is still there.

I think you might be confusing this case with the case of explicit capture, i.e. { [pet] in ... }. These have different behaviours. See also: https://forums.swift.org/t/closure-with-explicit-vs-implicit-capturing/52776

I know how capture list works. If working with value types, capture list creates an immutable copy of a variable/constant and this copy is independent from the original variable/constant.  but I thought, that when it comes to reference types, closures and functions creates their own copy of a reference, EVEN if I don't use the capture list(in closures), no? This also explains what causes a memory leak in the first code snippet. Since, if 'pet' inside the closures and outside the closure would be the same reference, then memory leak wouldn't happen.

Your's pet is captured as variable in closure. You can assign something to it and it will change outside of closure. In objective-c it's more clear: you should mark such variables by __block. So because you have var here and doesn't have capture list pet is created in heap instead of stack and shared without creating copies

Im sorry, but I still don't understand :( And I can't point out what I don't understand exactly, but ill try my best. The first question is, at the end of the day, is 'pet' inside the closure a whole new reference or the same reference? If it's the same reference, then how is it possible for a memory leak to occur in the first snippet? Isn't it supposed to be deleted by the end of the 'do' scope? Also how does the capture list affect the environment(heap/stack) the 'pet' is created in?

@henessybloom It is the same reference. You are assuming pet lives only as long as the do block, but it actually lives as long as the closure.

I'll try to get more information about it, thanks a lot, guys. Just one more thing, I know this is kind of an off-topic questions, but can you please tell me how does functions treat reference types? I suppose, that If its passed as an inout parameter, its the same reference, and if passed as a regular parameter, its the copy?

@henessybloom Escaping closures cannot capture inout parameters.

No-no, I meant just the regular functions. Like here
class SomeClass {
    
}

func someFunc(_ x: inout SomeClass) {
    
}

var someInstance = SomeClass()

someFunc(&someInstance)

Im not yet that experienced to know what @escaping is. it seems like comments does not support code snippets, I hope you can figure out what I wrote there =(

The closure in your code, { print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }, is escaping, because you are assigning it to the property of an object. For non-escaping closures, I think the question about inout is kind of moot.

Oh I see, once again thanks a lot

Your reasoning would be correct if the closure were
{ [pet] in print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }

The above closure indeed has a strong reference to the Animal object, and the Animal object has a strong reference to the closure, creating a retain cycle.
However, your closure captures the variable pet. It has a strong reference to whatever object the variable pet refers to. If pet is set to nil, then the closure will not have a strong reference to the object that pet previously refers to.
Compare:
do {
    var pet: Animal? = Animal()
    // this closure captures the variable 'pet', so 'pet = nil' later will affect what this closure does
    pet?.command = { print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }
    let pet2 = pet
    // the 'pet' in the closure now becomes nil
    pet = nil
    pet2?.command() // this prints "Bobby"
}

do {
    var pet: Animal? = Animal()
    // this closure captures the object referred to by 'pet' at this moment
    pet?.command = { [pet] in print(pet?.name ?? "Bobby") }
    let pet2 = pet
    // this does not change the object captured by the closure
    pet = nil
    pet2?.command() // this prints "Fischer"
}

Even after the do block is done, the variable pet is not "deleted" - it is held in the closure. Since it is captured by a closure, it gets put on the heap, and does not stay on the stack.

I've heard from someone that references are being copied when captured by the closure even without the usage of the capture list, but I guess they were wrong. This makes things much clearer, thanks a lot!
